# Unique a pile of email addresses, some multiples on a single line separated by a semi colon

Tags: arrays, powershell, unique, import-from-csv, email-address

I have a list of servers and each one has at least one email distribution list associated with it as a "stakeholder" we can contact for downtime etc.

When we do maintenance we email all the distribution lists of the implicated servers and there is duplication as many servers can all have the same one email contact (SERVER1, SERVER2). The other issue is that a single server could also have multiple email contacts (SERVER3), separated by a semicolon so they parse correctly when pasted into Outlook.

```
SERVER1     group1@somewhere.com
SERVER2     group1@somewhere.com
SERVER3     group1@somewhere.com ; group23@somewhereelse.com
```

Right now, from a big array from a spreadsheet, I do either a `Get-Unique`:

```
$spreadsheetDataObject |
    select contacts, patchcycle |
    where {($_.patchcycle -eq "SpectreSat")} |
    Sort-Object contacts |
    select contacts |
    Get-Unique
```

Or a `-Unique off the`Sort-Objects`:

```
$spreadsheetDataObject |
    select contacts, patchcycle |
    where {($_.patchcycle -eq "SpectreSat")} |
    Sort-Object contacts -Unique |
    select contacts
```

And both get me the result:

```
group1@somewhere.com
group1@somewhere.com ; group23@somewhereelse.com
```

I would like to know the best way to unique "everything" so that the second line separated by the semi-colon would be split out and uniqued as well so the output looks like this:

```
group1@somewhere.com
group23@somewhereelse.com
```

What's the best way to do this and in how many steps? Split any email addresses separated by semicolon first into unique array elements and remove the `;` (not sure how to do this) and then do a unique on the new array? Maybe a trim as well in case spaces are hiding around the `;`.

Comment: `$string -split ";"` will take a string, split it at every semicolon, and return an array with one portion per segment that it found, dropping the semicolons. For example, `$baz = "foo;bar" -split ";"` will return an array `$baz` where `$baz[0] -eq "foo"` and `$baz[1] -eq "bar"`.

Comment: I've never used split, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `ForEach-Object` between `Where-Object` and `Sort-Object` where you split the contacts into individual addresses. Since you don't seem to need the `patchcycle` property after the `Where-Object` anymore you can simply pass the output to the pipeline without constructing new objects first:

```
... | Where-Object { $_.patchcycle -eq 'SpectreSat' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.contacts -split '\s*;\s*' } |
    Sort-Object -Unique
```

The regular expression `\s*;\s*` automatically removes whitespace surrounding the semicolons.

Comment: Awesome! That appears to work like a charm! I was able to run it but it turns out I have some more whitespace in my email addresses that must be present outside the ";" that are still causing dupes. I will try to address that beforehand. Thanks!